# What's your most reused class?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

Every programmer ends up with a set of utility classes after a while. Some of them are true programming pearls and they are reused in several of your projects. For example, in java:

```
 class Separator {

        private String separator;
        private boolean called;

        public Separator(String aSeparator) {
            separator = aSeparator;
            called = false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (!called) {
                called = true;
                return "";
            } else {
                return separator;
            }
        }
    }
```

and:

```
public class JoinHelper {

    public static <T> String join(T... elements) {
        return joinArray(" ", elements);
    }

    public static <T> String join(String separator, T... elements) {
        return joinArray(separator, elements);
    }

    private static <T> String joinArray(String sep, T[] elements) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Separator separator = new Separator(sep);

        for (T element : elements) {
           stringBuilder.append(separator).append(element);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

What is **your** most reused class?

Comment: Make this community wiki, please. Otherwise, you risk closure.

Comment: Couldn't you just use StringUtils#join from Apache's commons-lang?

Comment: that is only an exaple of possible "homegrow" utility class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A utility class that has logging and email functionality.  An extensions class that contains extension methods.  A reporting class that basically harness the reporting services web service and makes it easy to stream reports as excel, pdf, etc.

**Examples...**
1.) Utility Class (static)

```
   public static void LogError(Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog log = new EventLog();
        if (ex != null)
        {
            log.Source = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventLog"].ToString();
            StringBuilder sErrorMessage = new StringBuilder();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Url != null)
            {
                sErrorMessage.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            sErrorMessage.Append(ex.ToString());
            log.WriteEntry(sErrorMessage.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

2.) Extensions Class

```
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (condition)
            return source.Where(predicate);
        else
            return source;
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

[`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) - almost all my types extend it.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static short getLastDayOfMonth(short givenMonth, short givenYear)
{
    short lastDay = 31;
    switch (givenMonth)
    {
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            lastDay = 30;
            break;
        case 2:
            if ((int)givenYear % 4 == 0)
            {
                lastDay = 29;
            }
            else
            {
                lastDay = 28;
            }
            break;    
    }
    return lastDay;
}
```

Comment: Too bad this is buggy.  http://www.dataip.co.uk/Reference/LeapYear.php Your algorithms will return 29 for 1900, when it should be 28.

Why not use Joda time or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Most reused but boring:

```
public static void handleException(Exception e) throws RuntimeException {
    if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) e;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(e); //NOPMD
}
```

Less boring (also methods for building lists and sets):

```
/**
   * Builds a Map that is based on the Bean List.
   * 
   * @param items Bean List items
   * @param keyField Bean Field that will be key of Map elements (not null)
   * @return a Map that is based on the Bean List
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T, K> Map<K, T> buildMapFromCollection(final Collection<T> items,
                                                        boolean linkedMap,
                                                        final String keyField,
                                                        final Class<K> keyType) {
    if (items == null) {
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    if (keyField == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("KeyField is null");
    }

    final Map<K, T> result;

    if (linkedMap) {
      result = new LinkedHashMap<K, T>();
    } else {
      result = new HashMap<K, T>();
    }

    BeanMapper mapper = null;
    for (final T item : items) {
      if (mapper == null) {
        mapper = new BeanMapper(item.getClass());
      }
      final K key = (K) mapper.getFieldValue(item, keyField);
      result.put(key, item);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: You should rename it doNotHandleException(...) :)

Comment: Or just use Guava Throwables

Answer (score 1):

Logger class: Which logs the flow of control in a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration Reader/Setter: which reads the configuration from ini/xml file and sets the environment of the application

Answer (score 1):

Most reused? Hmmm...

boost::shared_ptr<> with boost::weak_ptr<>

probably most reused (also probably most bang-for-buck ratio)

Answer (score 1):

Globals

Just a simple class with static DBConnString, and a few other app wide settings.

Have reused the simple file in about 2 dozen projects since working with .Net

Answer (score 1):

A ConcurrentDictionary I wrote, which I now seem to use everywhere (I write lots of parallel programs)

Comment: It is here: http://concurrent.codeplex.com/ I wrote that a *very* long time ago though and I have no idea how good it is.