# How to implement a list fold in Java

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, folding

I have a List and want to reduce it to a single value (functional programming term "fold", Ruby term `inject`), like

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c") ... fold ... "a,b,c"
```

As I am infected with functional programming ideas (Scala), I am looking for an easier/shorter way to code it than

```
sb = new StringBuilder
for ... {
  append ...
}
sb.toString
```

Comment: Why don't you write a helper method and just call that? You can write your own functions.

Comment: Sure, I could write one using the code given. But only when I am sure there does not exist such a function.

Comment: Functional programming in Java? Tread softly, and wear thick boots.

Comment: I know this question was added in '09 but there is an answer way down that shows that this has been implemented in Java 8 and there are a lot of answers that rely on libraries when it is now a language feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a string `join()` method which Java has since 8.0. Try one of the methods below.

1. Static method [`String#join(delimiter, elements)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

   ```
   Collection<String> source = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
   String result = String.join(",", source);
   ```
2. [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface supports a fold operation very similar to Scala’s `foldLeft` function. Take a look at the following concatenating [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

   ```
   Collection<String> source = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
   String result = source.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   ```

   You may want to statically import `Collectors.joining` to make your code clearer.

   By the way this collector can be applied to collections of any particular objects:

   ```
   Collection<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
   String result = numbers.stream()
           .map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   ```

Answer (score 15):

To answer your original question:

```
public static <A, B> A fold(F<A, F<B, A>> f, A z, Iterable<B> xs)
{ A p = z;
  for (B x : xs)
    p = f.f(p).f(x);
  return p; }
```

Where F looks like this:

```
public interface F<A, B> { public B f(A a); }
```

As dfa suggested, [Functional Java](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava) has this implemented, and more.

Example 1:

```
import fj.F;
import static fj.data.List.list;
import static fj.pre.Monoid.stringMonoid;
import static fj.Function.flip;
import static fj.Function.compose;

F<String, F<String, String>> sum = stringMonoid.sum();
String abc = list("a", "b", "c").foldLeft1(compose(sum, flip(sum).f(",")));
```

Example 2:

```
import static fj.data.List.list;
import static fj.pre.Monoid.stringMonoid;
...
String abc = stringMonoid.join(list("a", "b", "c"), ",");
```

Example 3:

```
import static fj.data.Stream.fromString;
import static fj.data.Stream.asString;
...
String abc = asString(fromString("abc").intersperse(','));
```

Answer (score 10):

Given

```
public static <T,Y> Y fold(Collection<? extends T> list, Injector<T,Y> filter){
  for (T item : list){
    filter.accept(item);
  }
  return filter.getResult();
}

public interface Injector<T,Y>{
  public void accept(T item);
  public Y getResult();
}
```

Then usage just looks like

```
fold(myArray, new Injector<String,String>(){
  private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  public void Accept(String item){ sb.append(item); }
  public String getResult() { return sb.toString(); }
}
);
```

Comment: Still can't decide whether I'd rather call Injector#getResult Injector#yield.

Comment: In my opinion `yield` is more of a functional programming term and since `fold` is also a functional programming term, `yield` should be better to use.

Comment: the list parameter should be `Collection<? extends T> list`, not `super`, because list is a producer of Ts

Answer (score 8):

If you want to apply some functional aspects to plain old Java, without switching language [*although you could*](http://javaposse.com/index.php?post_id=482649) [LamdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/), [fork-join (166y)](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) and [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) are libraries that help you to add that syntactic sugar.

With the help of [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) you can use the [Joiner class](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
Joiner.on(",").join("a", "b", "c")
```

`Joiner.on(",")` is an immutable object so you might share it freely (for example as a constant).

You can also configure null handling like `Joiner.on(", ").useForNull("nil");` or `Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls()`.

To avoid allocating big strings while you are generating a large string, you can use it to append to existing Streams, StringBuilders, etc. through the `Appendable` interface or `StringBuilder` class:

```
Joiner.on(",").appendTo(someOutputStream, "a", "b", "c");
```

When writing out maps, you need two different separators for entries and seperation between key+value:

```
Joiner.on(", ").withKeyValueSeparator(":")
            .join(ImmutableMap.of(
            "today", "monday"
            , "tomorrow", "tuesday"))
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is a string "join" function which, unfortunately, Java does not have.  You will have to roll your own join function which shouldn't be too hard.

**Edit:** [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/) seems to have many useful string functions (including join).

Comment: Yeah. I just hope no-one in their right mind would choose the usage in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950751/how-to-implement-a-list-fold-in-java/951004#951004 over a call to StringUtils.join(), if the problem is *joining a bunch of Strings into one* in Java. :)

Comment: @Jonik: I hope no one in their right mind would be ready to introduce a new dependency just for a single method :)

Comment: Yep, but, once again, a typical project would benefit from using *lots of stuff* from libraries like Commons Lang or Guava. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) has `injectInto` (like Ruby and Smalltalk), `makeString` and `appendString`.  The following will work with your example:

```
String result1 = FastList.newListWith("a", "b", "c").makeString(",");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
FastList.newListWith("a", "b", "c").appendString(sb, ",");
String result2 = sb.toString();
Assert.assertEquals("a,b,c", result1); 
Assert.assertEquals(result1, result2);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately in Java you can't escape that loop, there are several libraries however. E.g. you can try several libraries:

- [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)
- [functionaljava](http://functionaljava.org/)
- specifically in your case you can reuse [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738039/whats-your-most-reused-class) of mine

Comment: Google Collections has a Function interface and a Lists.map method, but no equivalent of fold. It does, however, have a Joiner class that suits this particular application.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need a functional library for Java which supplies generic functors and functional projections like fold.  I've designed and implemented a powerful (by virtue) yet simple such library here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/FunctionalJava.aspx (I found the other libraries mentioned overly complicated).

Then your solution would look like:

```
Seq.of("","a",null,"b","",null,"c","").foldl(
    new StringBuilder(), //seed accumulator
    new Func2<StringBuilder,String,StringBuilder>(){
        public StringBuilder call(StringBuilder acc,String elmt) {
            if(acc.length() == 0) return acc.append(elmt); //do not prepend "," to beginning
            else if(elmt == null || elmt.equals("")) return acc; //skip empty elements
            else return acc.append(",").append(elmt);
        }
    }
).toString(); //"a,b,c"
```

Note that by applying fold, the only part that really needs to be thought out is the implementation for Func2.call, 3 lines of code which define an operator accepting the accumulator and an element and returning the accumulator (my implementation accounts for empty strings and nulls, if you remove that case then it's down to 2 lines of code).

And here's the actual implementation of Seq.foldl, Seq implements Iterable<E>:

```
public <R> R foldl(R seed, final Func2<? super R,? super E,? extends R> binop)
{
    if(binop == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("binop is null");

    if(this == EMPTY)
        return seed;

    for(E item : this)
        seed = binop.call(seed, item);

    return seed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 style (functional):

```
// Given
List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
String first = arr.get(0);

arr = arr.subList(1, arr.size());
String folded = arr.stream()
            .reduce(first, (a, b) -> a + "," + b);

System.out.println(folded); //a,b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java is not a functional programming language and does not have a good way to do what you want.

I believe the Apache Commons lib has a [function called join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.util.Collection,%20char)) that will do what you want though.

It will have to be good enough to hide the loop in a method.

```
public static String combine(List<String> list, String separator){
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        ret.append(list.get(i));
        if(i != list.size() - 1)
            ret.append(separator);
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

I suppose you could do it recursively:

```
public static String combine(List<String> list, String separator){
    return recursiveCombine("", list, 0, separator);
}

public static String recursiveCombine(String firstPart, List<String> list, int posInList, String separator){
    if (posInList == list.size() - 1) return firstPart + list.get(posInList);

    return recursiveCombine(firstPart + list.get(posInList) + separator, list, posInList + 1, seperator);
}
```

Comment: Probably the recursive solution (I didn't vote you down, btw). That's a great way to get a stack overflow.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Java doesn't handle these kinds of things well, because the recursive solution to these kinds of things is often the easiest to understand.

Comment: Indeed, recursiveCombine is tail-recursive, so potential for stack-overflow could be eliminated if JVM was smart enough to understand tail-recursion (a corner-stone of all functional languages).

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use `String.join()` with Java 8.

```java
    List strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    String joined = String.join(",", strings);
    System.out.println(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the support of lambdas we could do with the following code:

```
static <T, R> R foldL(BiFunction<R, T, R> lambda, R zero, List<T> theList){

     if(theList.size() == 0){
      return zero;
     }

     R nextZero = lambda.apply(zero,theList.get(0));

     return foldL(lambda, nextZero, theList.subList(1, theList.size()));                  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to fold the list, by keeping back the information of the nodes let behind and folding as we move forward.

```
public class FoldList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node a = new Node(1);
        Node b = new Node(2);
        Node c = new Node(3);
        Node d = new Node(4);
        Node e = new Node(5);
        Node f = new Node(6);
        Node g = new Node(7);
        Node h = new Node(8);
        Node i = new Node(9);
        a.next = b;
        b.next = c;
        c.next = d;
        d.next = e;
        e.next = f;
        f.next = g;
        g.next = h;
        h.next = i;

        foldLinkedList(a);

    }

    private static void foldLinkedList(Node a) {
        Node middle = getMiddleNodeOfTheList(a);
        reverseListOnWards(middle);
        foldTheList(a, middle);

    }

    private static Node foldTheList(Node a, Node middle) {
        Node leftBackTracePtr = a;
        Node leftForwardptr = null;
        Node rightBackTrack = middle;
        Node rightForwardptr = null;
        Node leftCurrent = a;
        Node rightCurrent = middle.next;
        while (middle.next != null) {
            leftForwardptr = leftCurrent.next;
            rightForwardptr = rightCurrent.next;
            leftBackTracePtr.next = rightCurrent;
            rightCurrent.next = leftForwardptr;
            rightBackTrack.next = rightForwardptr;
            leftCurrent = leftForwardptr;
            leftBackTracePtr = leftCurrent;
            rightCurrent = middle.next;
        }
        leftForwardptr = leftForwardptr.next;
        leftBackTracePtr.next = middle;
        middle.next = leftForwardptr;

        return a;

    }

    private static void reverseListOnWards(Node node) {
        Node startNode = node.next;
        Node current = node.next;
        node.next = null;
        Node previous = null;
        Node next = node;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = next;
        }
        node.next = previous;

    }

    static Node getMiddleNodeOfTheList(Node a) {
        Node slowptr = a;
        Node fastPtr = a;
        while (fastPtr != null) {
            slowptr = slowptr.next;
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next;
            if (fastPtr != null) {
                fastPtr = fastPtr.next;
            }
        }
        return slowptr;

    }

    static class Node {
        public Node next;
        public int value;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no such a function, but you could create something like the following, and invoke it whenever you need to.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FoldTest {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
        String s = fold( list, ",");
        System.out.println( s );
    }
    private static String fold( List<String> l, String with  ) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( String s: l ) {
            sb.append( s ); 
            sb.append( with );
        }
        return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1 ).toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: The `deleteCharAt` call really hurts my eyes. Also, you are only deleting the last char, no matter how long `with` is. Actually, it would be better to not append `with` at all in the end. In addition, when the list and `with` are both empty, an exception will be thrown.