# Iterable Sum in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a library that does this:

```
public class Iterables{
    private Iterables() {}

    public static <T> int sum(Iterable<T> iterable, Func<T, Integer> func) {
        int result = 0;
        for (T item : iterable)
            result += func.run(item);
        return result;
    }
}

public interface Func<TInput, TOutput> {
    TOutput run(TInput input);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There are basically two useful libraries that can help with this; [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) and [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

What you are trying to do is basically two operations, first mapping, then reduction. I've never used Commons Collections to any extent myself so I can't tell you more about that, but I know there is no support for reduction (or folding) in Google Guava at least (see [Issue 218](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=218)). This is not too hard to add yourself though (not tested):

```
interface Function2<A, B> {
  B apply(B b, A a);
}

public class Iterables2 {
    public static <A, B> B reduce(Iterable<A> iterable,
      B initial, Function2<A, B> fun) {
        B b = initial;
        for (A item : iterable)
             b = fun.apply(b, item);
        return b;
    }
}
```

That way you can combine it with Guavas Iterables.transform() like so:

```
class Summer implements Function2<Integer, Integer> {
    Integer apply(Integer b, Integer a) {
        return b + a;
    }
}

class MyMapper<T> implements Function<T, Integer> {
    Integer apply(T t) {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And then (provided you've import static'ed the relevant classes):

```
reduce(transform(iterable, new MyMapper()), 0, new Summer());
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950751/how-to-implement-a-list-fold-in-java).

Comment: Could you fix your example? I get `The method apply(A) in the type Function<A,B> is not applicable for the arguments (B, A)` on the fun.apply() line.

Comment: Maybe. Probably not. The answer is 5 years old, just use Java 8 streams :)

Answer (score 10):

Since Java 8 is now out getting a sum on collections is simple:

```
collection.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Unfortunately stream is not available on iterables but one can always convert. Arrays are easier:

```
LongStream.of(1, 2, 3).sum()
```

Comment: In Java 8, you could use
StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), false)
to get a stream if "values" is of type Iterable<Integer>

Answer (score 9):

Java is not a functional langugae and often it simpler and faster to just using a plain loop.

You could write something like

```
List<String> list = /* ... */
int totalLength = Iterables.sum(list, new Func<String, Integer>() {
    public Integer run(String input) {
        return input.length();
    }
});
```

however IMHO its shorter and simpler to just write.

```
List<String> list = /* ... */
int totalLength = 0;
for(String s: list) totalLength += s.length();
```

When closures become standard in Java, this will change but for now a loop is often the best way.

Comment: Just remember though: `shorter != easier to read` , a cognitive bias most programmers aren't aware of.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat agreed which is something to watch out for when using lambda, esp nested lambdas. e.g `a -> b -> a > b` is short but not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Functional Java has a sum method:

http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/function/Integers.html#sum%28fj.data.List%29

Here's an example:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
ints.add(3);
int sum = Integers.sum(fj.data.List.iterableList(ints));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use [Lamdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) - a library to manipulate collections in a pseudo-functional and statically typed way:

```
sum = Lambda.sum(iterable);
```

It can also do other types of aggregation or you can addd you own Aggregators:

```
sum = Lambda.aggregate(seq, new InitializedPairAggregator<Integer>(0) {
    protected Integer aggregate(Integer first, Integer second) {
        return first + second;
    }
});
```

See [Features](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures) for other examples.