# Shortest form of getting average of an ArrayList elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, average

By shortest form I mean least number of lines of java codes. I would like to get average value of items of an ArrayList of integer values.
For example for the ArrayList **ar**:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
```

I am looking for something like

```
ar.Average()
```

or

```
ar.Sum()
```

or

```
Arrays.Average(ar)
```

PS. I know we can do it in a loop. Just looking for a shorter alternative;

Comment: Related (but not exact duplicate): ["Iterable Sum in Java?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4758341/978917)

Comment: So you're looking for a method that is already present? Checked the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

Comment: It's about 5 lines in a loop, and you can put that into a method which you call from elsewhere. Are you *really* that bothered by introducing one new - and short - method?

Comment: I know, but see it is a classic problem and I thought there should be something in ArrayList or similar utilities by now.

Comment: I checked the doc for ArrayLisr and Arrays, there is none. That is why I said SIMILAR

Comment: ArrayList can contain anything, not just integers, so it doesn't make sense that it would contain math specific functions.

Comment: Do you mean the shortest do-it-yourself implementation, or do you mean the shortest way to do it using the standard library, or do you mean the shortest way to do it using free-to-use libraries? As a side note, Dijkstra in "the humble programmer" thought this phenomenon of "one-liners" is counterproductive since it diverts attention from what is essential about quality programming.

Comment: I know that's example code but method first letter should be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Math library such as Apache Commons Math.

http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/index.html

Specifically a SummaryStaticics object (http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html#line.123). Though for something like average, it probably isn't worth importing a library.

Answer (score 0):

The [commons math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/) contains a [mean](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html) as well as whatever else you probably want for simple statistics. Perhaps exactly what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Java 8:

```
double average = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)
                       .stream()
                       .map(Integer::intValue)
                       .average()
                       .getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code is a always a quite meaningless measure, but if that is what you care about:

```
int sum=0;for(Integer i:ar)sum += i;System.out.println(sum);
```